# Input element overflows the container

Tags: html, css, list

The input overflows the parent container when the text is too long.

I am looking at how to wrap the text inside of the element. I tried `word-break`, `text-wrap` but nothing worked.

```
    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="test" class="submit" value="sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text">
    </div>
```

Comment: yes, change the button text

Comment: Probably the input has a padding-left?

Comment: Could you show the CSS you have currently?

Comment: I had `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;` for `body`. Removing those fixed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`white-space:normal` seems to work fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge …

```css
div { width: 400px; }
input[type=submit] { white-space:normal; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="submit" name="test" class="submit" value="sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text">
</div>
```

Comment: I needed the all the text to be visible. Adding ` white-space:normal;`  did the trick! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Just specify a `max-width` on the button:

```css
.submit {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="submit" name="test" class="submit" value="sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text" />
</div>
```

Notice that you can also style the overflow using the `text-overflow` property.